# In XSLT, how can I insert matching tags that apply to different templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm very new to XSLT and just haven't been able to find a solution yet to my problem.  I have an xml file that looks like (and I can't change the way this xml looks, realizing it's a bit odd):

```
<account>
    <name>accountA</name>
</account>
<period>
    <type>priormonth</type>
</period>
<period>
    <type>currentmonth</type>
</period>
<account>
    <name>accountB</name>
</account>
<period>
    <type>priormonth</type>
</period>
<period>
    <type>currentmonth</type>
</period>
```

The xml file can have a **variable** number of account/period/period datasets but they are always in that order.

I've got an xsl file which looks like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="account">
    <name> <xsl:value-of select="name"/> </name>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="period">
    <type> <xsl:value-of select="type"/> </type>
</xsl:template>
```

The above works great because it deals with the multiple account/period/period occurrences and my output comes out like:

```
<name>accountA</name>
<type>priormonth</type>
<type>currentmonth</type>
<name>accountB</name>
<type>priormonth</type>
<type>currentmonth</type>
```

However, I'm wanting to have some additional tags inserted so that the output actually looks like:

```
<account>
    <name>accountA</name>
    <period>
        <type>priormonth</type>
        <type>currentmonth</type>
    </period>
</account>
<account>
    <name>accountB</name>
    <period>
        <type>priormonth</type>
        <type>currentmonth</type>
    </period>
</account>
```

Is there a way of doing this?  Apologies if my terminology is not quite right. 
Thanks

Comment: please mark the accepted answer if any.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="account">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <period>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::period[generate-id(preceding-sibling::account[1]) = generate-id(current())]/*" />
      </period>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="period" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The select statement is a bit convoluted, but what it basically does it select all `period` siblings following each `account` element, where the first `account` element that precedes it is the current one.

Answer (score 1):

The following XSLT assumes that the xml source is exactly as presented in your question (apart the missing root which makes the source document not well formed). In this case you do not need identity transform. Moreover, if really your `account` needs only the first next two `period` you can use a simpler XPath.

---

**XSLT 1.0** tested under **Saxon-HE 9.2.1.1J**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="account"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="account">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="name" />
            <period>
                <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::period[position()&lt;=2]/type" />
            </period>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="period" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <account>
        <name>accountA</name>
    </account>
    <period>
        <type>march</type>
    </period>
    <period>
        <type>currentmonth</type>
    </period>
    <account>
        <name>accountB</name>
    </account>
    <period>
        <type>priormonth</type>
    </period>
    <period>
        <type>currentmonth</type>
    </period>
</root>
```

Gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <account>
      <name>accountA</name>
      <period>
         <type>march</type>
         <type>currentmonth</type>
      </period>
   </account>
   <account>
      <name>accountB</name>
      <period>
         <type>priormonth</type>
         <type>currentmonth</type>
      </period>
   </account>
</root>
```

Comment: @Flynn1179: mmm, I think OP means variable number of datasets composed by the sequence `account/period/period`. Anyway I was clear in my answer header.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP did say that the number of elements could be variable; a solution that requires there to be exactly two `period` elements will probably not work.. actually, you could be right, but I read it differently. To be honest though, I'd still recommend a more general solution anyway, on general principle (pun fully intended :))

Comment: Thanks for both responses.  Very helpful.  I used the second response with a few modifications (my input file is actually a bit more complicated) but was able to get the desired results.  Thanks!!

Comment: I've found one more odd thing in my period template. In addition to the "type" fields, I also have some numeric data.  In the period template, I check for non-zero values on numeric fields.  If the number is zero, an empty tag gets shown.  This isn't happening.  It is like the "if" is being ignored or else the number is being converted to text?  Is this behavior because of the "copy-of"?  What can be done to resolve?....thanks

Comment: @kag: you'll probably need to show a sample of the XML and the XSLT you're trying to use. For that you might as well post a separate question.

Comment: @empo: +1 for practicality. :-) Also I interpreted the question the way you did.

Comment: @LarsH: thanks...will post as another question.  i'm trying to give a simplistic example rather than my whole xml/xslt because it's quite large.

Comment: @kag: if the following question is complex enough create a new post otherwise extend this one. comments are a narrow place for that.